# Bold text in Google play App Description?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, mobile-application

Maybe it's long time but I just noticed that there is no bold text in description any more, right?

Before I used to put some text in  tags and it was bold. Did Google change formatting or just removed it at all. Is there any chance to have bold text in Google play App description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google Play has removed it completely, there is no other way to do this.

But you still can use emojis in the description.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Google Play has removed the formatting option.** And I personally don't know any other option for doing this.